# Inserting syntax hilighted code inside mathematical equations

Tags: math-mode, listings

I'm using some mathematical function notation for expressing relational algebra, in which I want to express the predicates using a specific functional language (e.g. OCaml).

```
\[\sigma_{\begin{lstlisting}[language=[Objective]Caml]
 fun x -> x > 0
\end{lstlisting}}(R)\]
```

An error is returned:

1. Missing \endgroup inserted
2. Display math should end with $$

Is there a way to safely wrap the part of code which I want syntax hilighted with a specific language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to using `\lstinline` to get inline-mode typesetting, you need to encase the `\lstinline{...}` directive in a `\text{...}` wrapper, to enable the functioning of `\bfseries`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\sigma_{\text{\lstinline[language={[Objective]Caml}]{fun x -> x > 0}}}(R)$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by using `\lstinline` instead of the `lstlisting` environment.